# Phpmyadmin page won't load

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm working on a login page in VSC. The codes I'm trying to use are PHP and MYSQL. PHP is working just fine, but I can't open phpmyadmin to start working on the MySQL portion.

I've searched for answers in the other forums, but none of the solutions have worked. I don't see any errors when I start Apache and MySQL on XAMPP. When I look in the logs, I see that it says "FEEDBACK is disabled" But that's about it.

I think I know why this is happening. On XAMPP, I changed the ports for Apache and MySQL. It was the only way I could view webpage on localhost. Apache's SSL port is 4443 and the main port is 8080. MySQLs main port is 3306.

Will phpmyadmin not work unless I change the port numbers back? Or is there something else I'm missing?

The log is below

````
3:04:20 PM  [main]  Windows Version:  Home  64-bit
3:04:20 PM  [main]  XAMPP Version: 8.0.10
3:04:20 PM  [main]  Control Panel Version: 3.3.0  [ Compiled: Apr 6th 2021 ]
3:04:20 PM  [main]  Running with Administrator rights - good!
3:04:20 PM  [main]  XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
3:04:20 PM  [main]  Checking for prerequisites
3:04:20 PM  [main]  All prerequisites found
3:04:20 PM  [main]  Initializing Modules
3:04:20 PM  [main]  Starting Check-Timer
3:04:20 PM  [main]  Control Panel Ready
3:04:24 PM  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache service...
3:04:25 PM  [Apache]    Status change detected: running
3:04:27 PM  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL service...
3:04:28 PM  [mysql]     Status change detected: running
3:09:45 PM  [main]  Executing "services.msc"```
````

Comment: Yes phpmyadmin searches for mysql in the specified port, so change pho myadmins ini file

Comment: Where is the ini file? I don't see it directly under the phpmyadmin folder.

Answer (score 0):

The file name should be config.inc.php
Default path:

```
/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Or if you install phpmyadmin using yum in RHEL/CentOS it could be:

```
/etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php
```

The line should be something like that

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '';
```

Just add the new MySQL port between the single quotes

Comment: I'll remember this for next time. Since changing the ports didn't work. I reinstalled XAMPP and now everything's working fine